# Keeping backup of everything in DB2 version 7

Tags: db2

I am trying to keep backups of almost everything from a DB2 version 7, including **Tables**, **Views**, **Triggers** and **Indexes**. I am currently experimenting with db2look and db2move commands as shown below, but I am able to keep only the DDL and the Tables.

Command to keep the DDL

```
db2look -d CC_DEV -e -a -o CC_DEV_DDL.sql
```

Command to keep the Tables with their data

```
db2move CC_DEV export
```

Is this enough to keep what I need in case of a disaster? Do I need anything else?

Comment: What does "almost everything" mean exactly?  You don't mention functions or procedures, grants, db2 registry settings, db cfg settings, dbm cfg settings, node directory , db directory, nicknames, transaction logs.  If you want your data to be in a format readable by current versions of tools, better to export IXF files (and/or csv/asc files) manually (in addition to db2move export), in case later versions cannot cope with antique versions formats).

Comment: Thank you, the project is intended to be continued with the same version of DB2

Comment: wow a project in 2022 that is using a Db2-version 7, from circa 1999 , that's quite unusual.

Comment: @mao yup, it is, but that's unfortunately my task, to keep working with these versions... :/

Comment: What's wrong with `db2 backup` command for all things related to s database) + `db2cfexp` for instance cfg & environment, if you are going to stay with the same db2 version & platform?